# Check if website contain my banner

Tags: php, file-get-contents

### My situation

I've got a list of "partners" who should have added my banner to their site, somewhere on their site... So I need to check for it, and as it's a list of 200+ website's I'm writing a script for it in PHP.

My first thought, easy job! Using a `get_file_contents` and then search for my banner, then search for every links on the website and do a search again on my banner for every page.

---

### The problem

This is taking very, very long. As some pages have 50+ links on their site it's going to get almost 200*50 a page using `get_file_contents`.

---

### My script

```
$banners = array(
     // All my banner names => banner url's I need to search for
);
$dealers = array(
    // all partner names => website url of partner
);
foreach($dealers as $dealer => $url) {
    $i = 0;
    echo $dealer;
    // HTML ophalen van de homepage
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    foreach($banners as $banner => $banner_url) {
        if(preg_match("/" . $banner_url . "/", $content) == TRUE) {
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $stripped_file = strip_tags($content, "<a>");
    preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $stripped_file, $matches);

    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        if (strpos($match,'http') !== false) {
            $level = file_get_contents($match);
            foreach($banners as $banner => $banner_url) {
                if(preg_match("/" . $banner_url . "/", $content) == TRUE) {
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $match = $url . $match;
            $match = str_replace("//", "/", $match);
            $match = str_replace("http:/", "http://", $match);
            $match = str_replace("https:/", "https://", $match);
            $level = file_get_contents($match);
            foreach($banners as $banner => $banner_url) {
                if(preg_match("/" . $banner_url . "/", $content) == TRUE) {
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($i > 0) {
        echo " | Banner found <br />";
    } else {
        echo " | No banner <br />";
    }
}
```

---

### My question

> Is their any other spyder-like solution to speed up this script, or do I maybe need to set a cron and do a run for every X seconds or so to do just one website a time?

Comment: I do not have a solution to your problem just a suggestion from when i did something similar. Create a script banner.php that displays the banners (using parameters for the different banners) and log the HTTP_REFERER domain and then just check this list once a day?

Comment: i won't bother writing a php script, a normal beautifulsoup based python script will do the kill

Comment: This will be hard to see in the case of `width:0px`. The link will be there but not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scraping a website’s HTML to see if it contains a banner isn’t really the best way to go about this. What happens if you have 2,000 websites that are supposed to host your banner? That’s a lot of work for a PHP script and the server executing that script.

An alternative solution would be to have a PHP script that serves your banner image, but on doing so it logs a view of the site that’s implemented. Therefore, you can see when your banner was “last seen” on a website, and if the “last seen” date was quite a while ago then that’s cause for concern and investigation.

A sample PHP script:

```
<?php
// banner.php

// log view
// create database connection first
$sql = "INSERT INTO `banner_views` (`domain`) VALUES (:domain)";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':domain', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$sth->execute();

// output image
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
readfile('banner.gif');
exit(;
```

Just make sure your `banner_views` table has a `timestamp` column that’s a `TIMESTAMP` data type, and its default value set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` so you know when the banner was “seen”.

Comment: That's actually a great idea, stupid I didn't thought about this myself..! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Yeah. You’ve also got the problem of if the website owner changes your code, i.e. changes the `alt` attribute or adds their own tracking code to your banner’s URL. That’ll trigger a false positive if downloading the web page’s HTML and checking for your pre-defined HTML snippet, even though the banner may be on there still.

Answer (score 0):

For wast solution I can recommend you use wget in recursive mode for download pages from site and save on your disk. After download just check pages for banner code. This is same as your solution but can be faster